# Array of objects to objects with properties as keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I need some help to get objects from an array of object with keys coming from nested properties of the objects in the initial array. This is the initial array :

```
[  
   {  
      "id":{  
         "colName":"columnA",
         "recId":"123"
      },
      "desc":"this is a description for A",
      "resCode":"-1"
   },
   {  
      "id":{  
         "colName":"columnB",
         "recId":"123"
      },
      "desc":"this is a  description for B",
      "resCode":"-1"
   },
   {  
      "id":{  
         "colName":"columnC",
         "recId":"234"
      },
      "desc":"description for column c ",
      "resCode":"-1"
   }
];
```

And my desired output would be this:

```
{
    123: {
        columnA: {
            desc: "this is a description for A",
            rescode: "-1"
        }
        columnB: {
            desc: "this is a description for B",
            rescode: "-1"
        }
    },
    234: {
        columnC: {
            desc: "description for column c ",
            resCode: "-1",
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use reduce to do so but I have an issue. I don't know how (and when) to "clear" the temp variable so I can only have column names belonging to one recId.

```js
    const initialArray =  [
     {
      "id": {
        "colName": "columnA",
        "recId": "123"
      },
      "desc": "this is a description for A",
      "resCode": "-1"
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "colName": "columnB",
        "recId": "123"
      },
      "desc": "this is a  description for B",
      "resCode": "-1"
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "colName": "columnC",
        "recId": "234"
      },
      "desc": "description for column c ",
      "resCode": "-1"
    }
  ];
    let temp = {};
    const mappedObj = initialArray.reduce((obj, item) => {
      temp[item.id.colName] = Object.assign({}, {desc: item.desc}, {resCode: item.resCode} );
      obj[item.id['recId']] = Object.assign({},  temp);
      return obj;
    }, {});
    console.log(mappedObj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to maintain a temp variable outside of reduce, you can simply process the same actions in reduce itself

```js
const initialArray =  [
     {
      "id": {
        "colName": "columnA",
        "recId": "123"
      },
      "desc": "this is a description for A",
      "resCode": "-1"
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "colName": "columnB",
        "recId": "123"
      },
      "desc": "this is a  description for B",
      "resCode": "-1"
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "colName": "columnC",
        "recId": "234"
      },
      "desc": "description for column c ",
      "resCode": "-1"
    }
  ];
    const mappedObj = initialArray.reduce((obj, item) => {
      obj[item.id.recId] = {...(obj[item.id.recId] || {}), [item.id.colName]: {desc: item.desc, resCode: item.resCode}}
      return obj;
    }, {});
    console.log(mappedObj);
```